# Bug in submitting post with numeric ordering

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

I tried the following post:

> My application allows the user to take a picture in the camera/or
>   choose from his photo library.
>
> I would like the posted image to be in resolution 650X550
>
> However I see:
>
> 1. After this code the size is 320X480
>
>    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary
>        *)editingInfo
>        {
>            NSLog(@"The height is %f",image.size.height);
>        }
> 2. When I submit the image like this - I retrieve it in 1024X480
>
>    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myurl/upload/"]
>      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
>      timeoutInterval:60];

The question couldn't be formatted with code blocks. Only when I removed the numbers (1,2) I could format it.

I think that it's a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bullet points, you need to indent code blocks with *8* spaces:

> 1. After this code the size is 320X480
>
>    ```
>    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
>        {
>            NSLog(@"The height is %f",image.size.height);
>        }
>    ```
> 2. When I submit the image like this - I retrieve it in 1024X480
>
>    ```
>    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myurl/upload/"]
>    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
>    ```

This is not a bug, this is how markdown works.

Comment: Well, the 1 and 2 are not part of the code! each one has to be formatted separately

Comment: To make a code block, you need to indent from the *current* indentation level. Having a list creates a new indentation level - hence, you need to indent another four spaces from *that* level.

Comment: If my question is duplicated - so maybe delete it no?

Comment: @Odelya: What makes you think that in my post the number bullets are part of the code?

Comment: @Odelya: No need to delete. It'll be closed when enough votes have been accumulated and then will serve to help others find the original post.

Comment: You are right. It's not part of the code - it looked to me at the beginning since you put it with the grey background