# Stack Overflow fails to format the code in this answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting

Stack Overflow seems to fail to format the code I posted in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15485942/352672

I added extra new lines so at least the lines can be distinguished. If you remove them, it is worse as all the text is put together.

Comment: It's a Markdown ambiguity: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item

Comment: Thank you for fixing my answer and the link to the culprit bug!!

Comment: This is clearly mentioned in "Code" section of Markdown help (click orange question mark button): *If you want to have a preformatted block within a list, indent by eight spaces*. Not a bug.