# Consecutive lists of different types are nested

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

Given the following Markdown:

```
- Unordered Item 1
- Unordered Item 2
- Unordered Item 3

1. Ordered Item 1
2. Ordered Item 2
3. Ordered Item 3
```

The second list will be nested under the first list:

- Unordered Item 1
- Unordered Item 2
- Unordered Item 3

  1. Ordered Item 1
  2. Ordered Item 2
  3. Ordered Item 3

A bit unexpected since I never indented the second list. Also, if both lists are of the same type (ordered or unordered), they aren't nested.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99637 (for code blocks, but same solution works, and I think this one is also by design.)