# Backquoted code text rendered

Tags: bug, markdown

Sometimes, backquoted tt text is rendered with an extra space and sometimes not.

Have an itemized list:

- `A` variable A is just rendered without surrounding spaces
- `B` variable B here are some mysterious spaces around the B, but otherwise OK

  Program code with A and B - rendered as regular text, but indented, This seems to be a feature according to 
  [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

  Another par

---

```
Nicely rendered after an hline
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, it's *supposed* to have the extra padding. For some reason inline code at the beginning of a list does not wrap the first item in a paragraph like it should.

Comment: @animuson: Really? It does not pad for **all** itemsin the following case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005036/can-someone-describe-this-prolog-code-step-by-step/20006664#20006664

Comment: It's definitely not supposed to do that. The padding is supposed to be there.