# <text bugs SE body messages

Tags: support, markdown

Seems like using `<text` bugs the message in SO, here is one example:

This text here only ends at the dot by the end of it, however because of

So as you can see the above text should have ended at the dot but due to the above mentioned combination it cuts it half way and if you look at the source you will see there is more after it.

Comment: It's probably trimming it because it looks like HTML. In your example you used `'<test'`, not `'<text'`, so it doesn't look for `text` specifically

Comment: Shouldn't it be just displayed as text instead? And the text doesn't matter.

Comment: You can achieve the same effect with < followed by any letter (and probably other symbols). Nothing special about `<text`.

Comment: @NickStauner indeed removed the single quotes, unneeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, it is a feature of Markdown as used on this site.

All words starting with a `<` character is interpreted as HTML. Any HTML tags not on the [HTML whitelist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) are then stripped.

Use backticks (`) to mark such text as code instead:

```
`<text`
```

renders as `<text`.

Comment: I see, that indeed makes sense as I can use for instance `<br>`. To my point of view I would think that if there is no termination it would get printed to screen instead of being parsed/removed half way.

Comment: @Prix See [my answer on a similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217926/inequalities-stripped-as-html-tags/217930#217930) for an explanation of why that isn't possible.