# Too small indent after nested list

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, list

I have post

```
2. > Why is no support for a optional spec-version in Maven?

 Maven has options for disabling Specifications and Implementations, so both are optional

  * `addDefaultSpecificationEntries` 
  * `addDefaultImplementationEntries`


    Read about
```

The problem is space between *addDefaultImplementationEntries* and *Read about*.

This is rendered as:

[image: to small space]

Post is visible here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21336830/516167

Comment: FWIW, in the meantime you could add a `<br />` between those two lines to make it look better.

Comment: Have a look here, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item

Comment: You can insert a blank line between each element of the list and the space will be much better.

Comment: @Matt, thanks, it looks better now :)

Comment: @Jerry, indeed :) thanks