# Line spacing after nested bullet points is inconsistent

Tags: bug, design, list

Correct duplicate: [Too small indent after nested list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217377/too-small-indent-after-nested-list)

---

Regarding the claimed duplicate (consecutive lists): that question was closed since it apparently follows Markdown spec in the Markdown => HTML conversion. This question is about CSS styling, not the HTML structure. Also, unlike the possible duplicate, this issue is not reproducible in other Markdown/CommonMark parsers.

It's also about a different issue: *not enough* space before the first unindented paragraph after nested unordered lists. The 'duplicate' is talking about issues with *extra* space between list items *even without nesting*, and only when an extra line break is added to the Markdown source (more line breaks do not affect this particular bug).

---

Paragraph breaks result in double line spacing everywhere *except* immediately after a *nested* bullet point. Top-level bullet points are fine, it's just the nested ones that exhibit this behaviour.

This is inconsistent. And it looks bad. It's a bit harder to tell that the line immediately after the list is supposed to be a new paragraph.

I cannot reproduce this behaviour with MarkdownPad 2 using the GitHub Flavored Markdown, Classic or CommonMark renderers with the GitHub, Markdown and None CSS options.

This behaviour also does *not* occur on the mobile version of SE sites, lending more credence to my theory that it's a CSS bug and not something actually intentional.

This appears to be because of an intentional `ul ul { margin-bottom: 0px; }` rule. Not entirely sure why that exists.

Example:

---

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vestibulum orci quis felis feugiat, quis sagittis ante fermentum.

  Curabitur sed nisl sagittis, fringilla neque quis, tristique mauris. Mauris fringilla elementum commodo.

  - Sed pretium vulputate vehicula. Nullam vestibulum eleifend risus, id luctus lacus fringilla id. Maecenas tortor nibh, mollis sed eros vel, maximus interdum risus.

  Maecenas rutrum nisl in venenatis sodales.

Phasellus eleifend sit amet dolor tempor porta. Phasellus tempus iaculis orci eu eleifend.

---

```
*  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vestibulum orci quis felis feugiat, quis sagittis ante fermentum. 

    Curabitur sed nisl sagittis, fringilla neque quis, tristique mauris. Mauris fringilla elementum commodo.

    * Sed pretium vulputate vehicula. Nullam vestibulum eleifend risus, id luctus lacus fringilla id. Maecenas tortor nibh, mollis sed eros vel, maximus interdum risus.

    Maecenas rutrum nisl in venenatis sodales. 

Phasellus eleifend sit amet dolor tempor porta. Phasellus tempus iaculis orci eu eleifend.
```

---

More:

[image: Screenshot with freehand circles]

[Sandbox tests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270159/187228)

Comment: It seems it is by design (ie following the markdown spec, see the dupe).

Comment: @DavidPostill Norepro on MarkdownPad with GFM, classic or CommonMark renderers and stylesheets. So either this is not explicitly in the spec (I think SE follows [CommonMark](http://spec.commonmark.org/) now) or one of the implementations is wrong. I don't think it's in the spec - it appears to be a CSS/styling issue, and after a brief glance at the spec I think it only specifies document structure.

Comment: Agree it's not a duplicate, I've also seen that other one when looking for dupe.

Comment: @TimStone Ok, I can agree that second one is a duplicate.