# Inconsistent spacing when using paragraphs in lists

Tags: feature-request, markdown, list

If you do something like this:

```
- This
- Is

 Some

- Text
```

You end up with some inconsistent spacing:

[image]

Is this a bug or is this a feature request to change this so the spacing above is the same?

This is similar to [Too small indent after nested list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217377/too-small-indent-after-nested-list), but not a duplicate as there aren't nested lists here and the spacing differences between these two makes me think the underlying cause is different.