# <pre> might not always behave like <pre> when it comes to indendation

Tags: discussion, markdown, code-formatting, pre

Someone might create a pre block in order to preserve indentation like in HTML but this does not work when the `pre` block is itself indented for a list. Is this behavior expected? I don't see any advantage.

```
<pre>
a
 b
  c
</pre>
* list
 <pre>
a
 b
  c
 </pre>
```

will turn into

```
a
 b
  c
```

- list

  ```
  a
  b
  c
  ```

/edit: Somewhat of a duplicate of [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item/99637#99637)
My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design as a way of Markdown works. A list item can use up to 4 spaces in front of each line as a way of indicating that it is still a part of the list item, so the Markdown parser strips out the first 4 spaces from each line within that list item because they are consumed as being a part of the list. Therefore, the final output of the actual pre block won't have those spaces available and won't be indented.

If the indentation is needed, you'll need to add an extra 4 spaces before each line so that Markdown can strip those out and still have the intended indentation left over.

```
a
 b
  c
```

- list

  ```
  a
   b
    c
  ```

Comment: Very good explanation! I feel like this process should somehow be made more obvious but I myself have no idea how. But I guess the mantra is that `<pre>` shouldn't be used to begin with (it just appears to be quicker sometimes).